# LWC - getPicklistValues on User Object

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lwc-wire-adapter

I am unable to retrieve picklist values from a User object field as the object doesn't have a record type (or master). Does anyone know if it's possible?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values

Ive tried without specifying a recordtypeid but no luck:-

```
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT })
userMetadata;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$userMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: FIELD})
picklistValues;
```

Comment: Found any solution? @Pete

Answer (score 1):

The `getPicklistValues` wire is buggy.  It only seems to work after setting a reactive variable within `connectedCallback`.  You'll have to assign `FIELD` to a member variable within `connectedCallback` in order to get this to work.

```js
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT })
userMetadata;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$userMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: '$myUserField'})
picklistValues;

connectedCallback() {
    this.myUserField = FIELD;
}
```

Comment: So that solution work fines for other objects like Account but as soon as I switch to the User object I get an error. I can only assume its because the User object doesn't have a record type?